# Error in installing pip packages inside a conda environment

Tags: python, pip, conda

I have been trying to install some python packages inside an anaconda3 environment. I however get an error like this:

```
 checking for lzma.h... yes
    checking for lzma_easy_buffer_encode in -llzma... no
    configure: error: liblzma development files not found

    The CRAM format may use LZMA2 compression, which is implemented in HTSlib
    by using compression routines from liblzma <http://tukaani.org/xz/>.

    Building HTSlib requires liblzma development files to be installed on the
    build machine; you may need to ensure a package such as liblzma-dev (on Debian
    or Ubuntu Linux), xz-devel (on RPM-based Linux distributions or Cygwin), or
    xz (via Homebrew on macOS) is installed; or build XZ Utils from source.

    Either configure with --disable-lzma (which will make some CRAM files
    produced elsewhere unreadable) or resolve this error to build HTSlib.
```

This error does not occur outside the conda enviroment. Could someone help please! Thank you!

Comment: Are you trying to run "PIP install ..." commands from anaconda prompt? Which Package are you trying to install?

Comment: Its a package named 'circlator'

Comment: any luck with this? I'm in the same boat with pysam in a conda env